# Dealing with state in <form> onSubmit React

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

So I'm starting to play around with React and am trying to wrap my head around state. I'm running into this issue with an onSubmit action on a form where it doesn't clear the input field after it's triggered. A fairly trivial issue, but I feel like there's a broader lesson in here about the whole component interacts that I'm missing.

```
'use strict'
const SmithyForm = React.createClass({
  displayName: "SmithyForm",

  getInitialState: function() {
    return { placeholder: "tweet" };
  },
  handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  },
  handleSubmit: function(event) {
    $.post('/test', { data: this.state.value }).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    });
    event.preventDefault();
   },
  render: function() {
    var placeholder = this.state.placeholder;
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" placeholder={placeholder} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <button> smithy</button>
        </form>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(<SmithyForm />, document.body )
```

So, my question is: What about my structure is preventing onSubmit from clearing the input field? (The code itself all works, component renders a form with a button. When the button is clicked the form makes an ajax request to a Node/Express backend which sends back the text entered into the input field.)

EDIT/ANSWER: The two pieces I missed were a default `value: ""` set in the getInitialState function and the subsequent call to that state in the render function `var value = this.state.value;`

One thing I'm still not as clear on as I'd like to be—which @Dan was alluding to—is the rerendering process of the component after it onSubmit is triggered.

Comment: Thanks @sean and @dan! Both of those were the exact answers I was looking for. 

sean, is the preventDefault preventing react default behavior? Or is my understanding of form default behavior just to narrow?

Comment: Though, interestingly. When putting this.setState into the promise as you both suggested it says it's not a function.

Comment: that means your `this` object is wrong.  keep a reference to it inside of `render()`: `var self = this;` and then reference it inside your onChange attribute: `onChange={self.handleChange}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `render()` function, you never specify what value should be displayed inside your `<input>` element.  When your component is rendered for the first time, it's empty; when your component is rendered subsequent times, React's behind-the-scenes DOM-diffing code does not detect any changes to the `<input>` element and therefore doesn't rebuild it (meaning whatever it contained before, it still contains now).

if you want to clear the `<input>` after form submit, you'll need to clear `state.value` inside of `handleSubmit()`, and then tell `<input>` to show `state.value` inside of `render()`.

Answer (score 2):

`event.preventDefault();` in the `handleSubmit` function means that all default behavior, including refreshing the page and clearing the field is disabled. It's up to you to clear the input box on your own.

The simplest way to do that would be to set the state back to either empty (which will then display the placeholder).

```
 $.post('/test', { data: this.state.value }).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
       this.setState({
            value: ""
        })
});
```